# (Simple placement issue) How do I make my ATM program not withdraw below $0?

Tags: java

This is for my Java 1 final.  I want it to kick back saying insufficient funds if the balance would go below $0 (and not create object Action -- which would be added to arraylist actions).

I believe I would use conditions in 2 places.  One in the getDouble() method in class Account, as well as in the object Action() in the class Action.  Perhaps in the main method though... I also don't exactly know what conditions I would put, and in the simplest way that won't mess up my program..

I also have a separate issue...

If I do a huge number, like 7 or 8 digits, it will return a different value, something like 200E7JK(example).  I assume the double is reaching some kind of maximum.  How can I fix this?

Main class:

public class ATM_Larrabee {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Action> actions = new ArrayList();



    Account acc = new Account("N/A", "N/A", 0.0);

    acc.displayWelcome();

    acc.createUsernamePassword();



    boolean options = true;

    while(options){

        acc.disconnect();

        System.out.println("\nWhat action would you like to take?");
        System.out.println("[ Account Balance: $" + Account.balance + " ]");
        System.out.println("\n- Type 'deposit' to make a deposit into your account.");
        System.out.println("- Type 'withdrawal' to make a withdrawal from your account.");
        System.out.println("- Type 'history' to see your history of transactions.");
        System.out.println("- Type 'exit' if you are finished.\n");

        String input = in.nextLine();



        if("exit".equals(input)){
            break;
        }



        if("history".equals(input)){

            Action actCopy = new Action("N/A", 0);

            System.out.println("\nBelow is a history of all transactions made:\n");

            for(int x = 0; x < actions.size(); x++){

                actCopy = actions.get(x);

                System.out.println(actCopy.getType() + ": $" + actCopy.getAmount());   
            }
        }



        if("deposit".equals(input) || "withdrawal".equals(input)){

            double actionAmount;
            actionAmount = acc.getDouble();

            Action act = new Action(input, actionAmount);

            actions.add(act);

            System.out.println("\nAction accepted.");
        }
    }     



    System.out.println("\nYour Account Balance Is: $" + Account.balance);
    System.out.println("\nThank you for using Really Boring Bank!");
}
}
```

Account class:

```
public class Account {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
static String username = "n/a";
static String password = "n/a";
static double balance = 0.0;



public Account(String u, String p, double b){

    username = u;

    password = p;

    balance = b;
}



public void displayWelcome(){

    String[] welcome = new String[3];

    welcome[0] = "Welcome to Really Boring Banking!";
    welcome[1] = "Hi there!  Welcome to Really Boring Banking!";
    welcome[2] = "Hello!  Welcome to Really Boring Banking!";

    Random rand = new Random();
    int r = rand.nextInt(3);

    if(r == 0){
        System.out.println(welcome[0]);
    }
    if(r == 1){
        System.out.println(welcome[1]);
    }
    if(r == 2){
        System.out.println(welcome[2]);
    }
}



public void createUsernamePassword(){

    System.out.println("\nAs a new member, you will first need to create a username and password.");
    System.out.println("\n[ Enter a username for your account: ]");

    String input = in.nextLine();
    setUsername(input);

    System.out.println("\n[ Enter a password for your account: ]");

    input = in.nextLine();
    setPassword(input);
}



public void disconnect(){

    Random rand = new Random();
    int r = rand.nextInt(5);

    if(r == 1){

        System.out.println("\n[ Connection to server lost.  Please log back into your account. ]");

        boolean loggedIn = false;
        boolean correctUsername = false;
        boolean correctPassword = false;

        while(!loggedIn){

            while(!correctUsername){

                System.out.println("\n[ Enter username: ]");

                String input = in.nextLine();

                if(Account.username.equals(input)){
                    correctUsername = true;
                    System.out.println("\nUsername Accepted");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("[ Incorrect username.  Please try again. ] ");
                }
            }    

            while(!correctPassword){

                System.out.println("\n[ Enter password: ]");
                String input = in.nextLine();

                if(Account.password.equals(input)){
                    correctPassword = true;
                    System.out.println("\nPassword Accepted");
                    loggedIn = true;
                    System.out.println("\nSuccessfully logged back into account: "+ Account.username + ".");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("[ Incorrect password.  Please try again. ] ");
                }
            }    
        }  
    }
}



    public double getDouble(){

    boolean validInput = false;

    double doub = 0.0;

    while (!validInput) {
        System.out.println("\n[ Please enter an amount: ]\n");

        String input = in.nextLine();

        try {

            doub = Double.parseDouble(input);

            validInput = true;

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            validInput = false;
        }
    }
    return doub;
    }



public String getUsername(){
    return Account.username;
}
public void setUsername(String u){
    username = u;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return Account.password;
}
public void setPassword(String p){
    password = p;
}

public double getBalance(){
    return Account.balance;
}
public void setSeed(double b){
    balance = b;
}
}
```

Action class:

```
public class Action {

double amount = 0;
String type;


// object for withdrawals and deposits (saved into an arraylist elsewhere)

public Action(String t, double a){

    type = t;

    amount = a;

    if("deposit".equals(type)){
        type = "deposit";
        Account.balance = Account.balance + a;
    }

    if("withdrawal".equals(type)){
        type = "withdrawal";
        Account.balance = Account.balance - a;
    }        
}


// gets and sets

public String getType(){
    return this.type;
}
public void setType(String t){
    type = t;
}    

public double getAmount(){
    return this.amount;
}
public void setAmount(double a){
    amount = a;
} 

}
```

Comment: Why haven't you already tried what you suggest?

Comment: I did and it messed it all up.  That's why I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You're not getting "something like" 200E7JK. Computer programming is exact business, you get something or your don't get it. Most likely, you didn't get the "JK" part because that doesn't make sense. However "200e7" is scientific notation, so that's very possible to get if you print out a large double value without any formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `balance` (and the other fields) `static` in `Account` makes everything a global (and means you can only have one `Account`). But, in the context of your question,

```
Account.balance = Account.balance - a;
```

needs a test to make sure `a` isn't greater than the `Account.balance` like

```
if (Account.balance >= a) {
    // Account.balance = Account.balance - a;
    Account.balance -= a;
} else {
    System.err.printf("%d is greater than %d and would be an overdraft%n",
            a, Account.balance);
}
```

in the long term though you'll need instance(s) of `Account` (so make them instance fields and create an instance of `Account`).